# Spreadsheet Alarm Toggle

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

At the moment I am searching for a method to toggle an alarm for all Users who are looking into the spreadsheet:

```
// creates a custom menu when the spreadsheet is opened
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('SWAT Pager')
    .addItem('Open SWAT Pager', 'openCallNotifier')
    .addToUi();

  // you could also open the call notifier sidebar when the spreadsheet opens
  // if you find that more convenient
  // openCallNotifier();
}

// opens the sidebar app
function openCallNotifier() {
  // get the html from the file called "Page.html"
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page') 
    .setTitle("SWAT Pager");

  // open the sidebar
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

// returns a list of values in column H
function getColumnE() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Operationen");

  // get the values in column H and turn the rows into a single values
  return sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
}
```

Thats the *code.gs*

Now what I would like to do is to set a dropdown menu where i can choose:

*Warning / No Warning.*

When i choose 'warning' I want an alarm sound playing, and on 'no warning' no sound.

Ive tried to change this script into it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="message">Keine Alarmierung </p>

    <audio id="Alarmierung">
      <source src="http://banhammer.bplaced.net/audio/spaceship_alarm.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <script>
    var lastTime = []; // store the last result to track changes

    function checkCalls() {

      // This calls the "getColumnE" function on the server
      // Then it waits for the results
      // When it gets the results back from the server,
      // it calls the callback function passed into withSuccessHandler
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (columnE) {
        for (var i = 0; i < columnE.length; i++) {

          // if there's a difference and it's a call, notify the user
          if (lastTime[i] !== columnE[i] && columnE[i] === "Alarmierung") {
            notify();
          }
        }

        // store results for next time
        lastTime = columnE;

        console.log(lastTime);

        // poll again in x miliseconds
        var x = 1000; // 1 second
        window.setTimeout(checkCalls, x);
      }).getColumnE();
    }

    function notify() {
      document.getElementById("Alarmierung").play();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      checkCalls();
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately it would not work. I would appreciate any suggestions from the community.

Comment: When you say it does not work, do you mean you get an error? Does the executions screen say anything? Can you expand on why this doesn't work in the way you expect it to? When you say you want a dropdown menu to choose if you want a sound or not, do you mean you want to choose for each user what kind of alert they get? Did you write this code or do you have a source?

Comment: No i dont get an Error. I have No Idea how to Change the Code that when in column E is the Word "warning" the Sound plays and when Ther is the Word "No warning" the Sound dient play

Comment: can you share a sample sheet? or at least a screen shot?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xdp0g6 There you can see the 2 Points i can chose in column E
So when the first one "Alarmierung" is set, i want that the sound plays for all Users who are looking into the spreadsheet.
When "Keine Alarmierung" is set there the sound need to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Proposed Solution

Your code was generally in the right direction, but it seemed to be doing some necessarily complicated things like:

```js
return sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
```

To get a value from E2, which can be done like this:

```js
return sheet.getRange("E2").getValue()
```

Though maybe you mean to aggregate the values like this for some reason, though it seemed to me that you were tying to get too much working too quickly and were getting confused with what goes where.

In any case, I took your code and simplified it to make an alarm work, which is what I believe your question was really directed towards:

#### Code.gs

```js
// This function creates a pop up called "Alarm"
function alarm(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, "Alarm");
}

// This is the function called by the client-side js in "Page.html"
// It returns a true or false value depending on the contents of E2
function checkAlarm() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Operationen");
  return sheet.getRange("E2").getValue() == "ALARM"
  
}
```

#### Page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="message">Keine Alarmierung </p>
    <script>
      // This is the call to the checkAlarm function in Code.gs.
      // It returns a true or false value which is passes into the function
      // playAlarm
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(playAlarm).checkAlarm();

      
      function playAlarm(bool){
        // If the value returned from "checkAlarm" is true
        // It created the HTML audio element and makes it play.
        if (bool == true){
          let audio = document.createElement("audio");
          audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
          audio.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay"); // So it plays automatically
          audio.setAttribute("style", "display:none"); // So the player is hidden

          let source = document.createElement("source");
          source.setAttribute("src","https://onlineclock.net/audio/options/police-car.mp3");
          source.setAttribute("type","audio/mpeg");

          audio.appendChild(source);
          document.appendChild(audio);
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Steps to get working.

1. Paste in the code.
2. Make sure it is not called `onOpen` - for an `onOpen` function to have access to the UI, it needs to be **installed** not a simple trigger. So go to the triggers in your project and **install** an onOpen one using the `alarm` function.
3. Make sure the value of `E2` in `Operationen` is `ALARM`.
4. Refresh the page and the alarm should play!

#### Notes

Your sound source `http://banhammer.bplaced.net/audio/spaceship_alarm.mp3` unfortunately does not work within Apps Script. I believe this is because it is an `http` origin and not a `https` origin. This is why I replaced this with another sound `https://onlineclock.net/audio/options/police-car.mp3` to get it working.

The script only checks for a match with `ALARM` in cell `E2` in `Operationen`. *Any* other value will result in no alarm.

#### References

- [ModalDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showModalDialog(Object,String))
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Ive done all you sayed with the Trigger, The script works also, but the Sound didn`t Play.
Only The Popup comes nothing else

Comment: Just to check, cell E2 says "ALARM" literally, right? Also you replaced all the code with my code? Including the sound link? It works for me.

Comment: yes ive replaced the howl code and yes The Cell shows up ALARM.
The Popup works but not the Sound. dont know why

Comment: also the trigger ive created: https://prnt.sc/xgj7uk

Comment: in function `checkAlarm` try and replace the return line with `return true` - now it should always play. If that doesn't work, are you in Chrome? Can you check the dev tools console once the pop up appears? Does your executions page show any errors?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xglbqi looks good no error, ive tryed it on Chrome and Opera both no sound only the Popup https://prnt.sc/xgld7v

Comment: Replace function `checkAlarm` completely, just make it `return true` nothing else, to see what happens.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xgm979 still the same, only popup and no sound.
did i need a sound codec installed for it or something?

Comment: you shouldn't need it, check the console in the browser in case...can I see the page.html?

Comment: Shure its the Page HTML you posted up there: https://prnt.sc/xgn480

Comment: On line 25, it is not the same link I used and the address is badly written => `https://https://` - use the one I did  - `https://onlineclock.net/audio/options/police-car.mp3`

Comment: Same as before, only popup no sound, or is the sound only playing for other users not for myself?

Comment: Now all is working fine, ive changed the sound to another one on another server. 
Ty for the Help :)